# how to ensure all rows/columns show up with pandas crosstab?

Tags: pandas

I am computing a simple crosstab for the purpose of a transition matrix like this:

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'to': ['A', 'B', 'B', None]}, 
                  columns=['from', 'to'])

pd.crosstab(test_df['from'], test_df['to'], dropna=False)
```

It produces the following matrix:

```
   A | B
---------
A  1 | 1
---------
B  0 | 1
```

I want it to include all transitions, even if they're 0, like the following:

```
   A | B | C
-------------
A  1 | 1 | 0
-------------
B  0 | 1 | 0
-------------
C  0 | 0 | 0
```

Is there some setting I am missing to do this?  I tried checking the options and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) at the end:

```
i = test_df[['from','to']].stack().unique()

new_df = (pd.crosstab(test_df['from'], test_df['to'],dropna = False)
            .reindex(index = i,columns=i,fill_value =0))
print(new_df)
to    A  B  C
from         
A     1  1  0
B     0  1  0
C     0  0  0
```

**Another approach:** [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
(test_df.pivot_table(index = 'from',columns = 'to',aggfunc = 'size',fill_value = 0)
        .reindex(index = i,columns = i,fill_value = 0))
```